# How to style HTML <option> controls as checkboxes

Tags: html, css

How do I style HTML  controls as they could display as checkboxes using CSS, I have searched through google but couldn't find any good help.

```
<html>
<select size="4" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckbx"> Data 01 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckbx"> Data 02 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckbx"> Data 03 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckbx"> Data 04 <br>
    ><input type="checkbox" name="ckbx"> Data 05 <br>

</select>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use custom selectbox

[jQuery Custom Select Box](http://mypocket-technologies.com/jquery/SelectBoxPlugin/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `style` selec dropdowns to have checkbox. You'll need to get this funcionality using javascript and emulate dropdown like appearance using css. There are a number of such scripts available, search for 'javascript multi select dropdown'

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with CSS. You would have to change the HTML to make checkboxes from a select element. Maybe you could use an XSLT to change the HTML.